# Theoretically, can a real religion exist in a high fantasy world?

Tags: religion, worldbuilding-process, gods, belief

In my world, there are multiple religions, and one of them is Christianity. While it exists in our world, there are some differences, including:

- Changing of locations and places
- A few characters are changed and removed
- Different rules
- Chain of command is sort of similar, but with major changes

And some similarities are:

- The deity is called "God"
- Branches of it, like real Christianity
- There is a Great Flood
- Similar names
- There is Jesus

While this I used Christianity as an example, there are also religions like Greek myhtology and a few others. I was wondering if it is possible for a real religion to exist in a high fantasy world? In my story, religion is not a major part of the plot, and it's very vague, only a few references, so it does not affect the main story, but rather the background of the worldbuilding. In addition, this is due to how societies form, and I was thinking if they would have ideas similar to ours.

Comment: You do realize that all five points of similarity are fulfilled by the Islamic religion? The deity is called God, the religion has several branches which considered each other heretical, there was a Great Flood (and there was Noah and the Ark etc.), has the same mythological characters with the same names (Abraham, Isaac, Solomon, David etc.), and yes, there is Jesus (the greatest prophet to come before prophet Mohammed, peace be upon him). And Mormonism is another religion which fulfills the requirements. So that here in the real world we have at least three religions sufficiently similar.

Comment: This seems like something that is entirely up to you and your world. If you want a real world religion to exist then it will exist, if you don't want a real world religion to exist in your world then it won't exist. You can even go wild and have people in your world believe in something that isn't true in your world, or have people disbeileve something that is objectively true in your world. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: define high fantasy, do gods actually exist, Christianity exists in a world where its god does not exist so a world where its god does exist may certainly make it more likely

Comment: "A few characters are changed and removed" Well, I must say, that sounds a bit pointless, if your removing them anyway why bother changing them first ;p

Comment: John's point is important. I say Christianity exists in a world where God does too, he says God doesn't, and as an author you can either declare God real, hint that He is, leave it open, hint that He isn't (boo), or exclude Him (bigger boo). It's worth considering where your story sits. @sphennings is right.

Comment: Adding the word "theoretically" to the question and broadening the scope does nothing to address the issues with this question. It's still your world and you still get to decide what can and cannot "theoretically" exist in it.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of authors have made high fantasy worlds with Christian analog religions.

The best one in my opinion is Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn by Tad Williams. Within the series there’s a religion that hits every criteria you mention, with the only difference being very minor alterations. (Instead of Jesus Christ being killed on the Cross, it’s Usires Aedon being killed on the execution tree)

Comment: Not to mention C. S. Lewis's *Narnia* books, and and S. M. Stirling's *Raj Whitehall* series, ...

Comment: @AlexP Yeah, there’s a massive number of them out there. I just wanted to plug Memory, Sorrow and Thorn because Tad Williams is one of my favorite authors

Answer (score 1):

I have certainly seen high fantasy using a Christian milieu.

The question may arise of how it arrived.  Portals that brought in missionaries?  Christians fleeing through a portal?

However, in many stories, the question would not arise, simply because it's not what the characters are thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It might pay to figure out the very basics of your church history/geography to make it work best.

In our world we had Jesus, the church at Jerusalem, the church spreading throughout the Roman world (with separated branches elsewhere such as Ethiopia, Persia and India), the Catholic church in Europe, the East-West split and then the Reformation.

If your Christians seem like Protestants, it might make the most sense for them to be in your version of America / Northern Europe and not have a big centralised church or priests or statues or incense, etc. There is no chain of command. Different if they're like Catholics; they'll have a hieratchical clergy with priests, etc.
Third world Christians could be either.

Bear in mind, Christians read books and make up x% of the population,and in any case there's no point getting cultures wrong needlessly, recognisable branches will make things seem more believable.

Remember that Christians won't put out a fatwa on your head or shoot anyone but that you are referencing things that a lot of people consider sacred. And also that a few cranks will take offense whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

Especially in this case: suppose your high fantasy world is actually ours, but drastically changed by [alien space bats.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_space_bats) If this point of divergence was sometime after the life of Jesus Christ, then this would satisfy the major similarities of God and Jesus. However, the structure could still be drastically different, due to the aforementioned alien space bats modifying “the prophets’ words”. As for the Great Flood story, this type of myth has [famously](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) been developed completely independently of modern Christianity, and [multiple times](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deucalion) to boot.

In short, I think all these conditions are plausible, especially with the freedom that a fantasy world allows, but it can also have a tenuous basis in reality if you so choose as well.